# How can I show a picture in design time in MFC picture control?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I don't want to do it in code, because I want to put controls on design time and so needs to know proper places. I draw bmp in onpaint. I mean statically not dynamically.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow These Steps

1. Drag Picture Control to you dialog.
2. Go to Picture Control propeties.
3. Change its "Type" to Bitmap.
   Now you can see "image" will become active.
4. just pass your BITMAP ID in it.

[image]